# How to write custom attribute directive for input basic validation in angular 4 reactive forms?

Tags: angular, typescript

I wants to create input custom attribute directive for validation like required, email,characters,numbers..

Comment: Could you write out your question in a little more detail because I'm not really sure what you are looking for. Do you want to create a form with validation on the form inputs? Do you want to create a custom validation for a form input? Or is it something else?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators try to do this. I make my own date validator with this.

Comment: I wants to check form control input  and wants to show  validation Messages  <input [form-error]="[characters,min,max,required] "> form-error is my custom directive.